# webview receiving link from qr code using zxing

Tags: android

Currently I'm using [ZXing Barcode Scanner](https://github.com/zxing/zxing). When I try to scan a qr code that has a url in it, it doesn't load and it shows `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`.

Meanwhile my other page that has its own url link that is not from an intent, it loads.

ERR_UNKNOWN_URL:

[image]

this is my code:

```
package com.project.ciisapp.ciis;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;


 public class scannner extends AppCompatActivity {
 private WebView wvv;



 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 wvv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvv);
 wvv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
 wvv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){



 @Override
 public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
  view.loadUrl(url);

  if (url.startsWith("http") || url.startsWith("https")) {
  return true;
  }else {
   wvv.stopLoading();
   wvv.goBack();
  Toast.makeText(scannner.this, "Unknown Link, unable to handle", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
return false;



   }});

   Intent intent=getIntent();
   String QRurl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("QRurl");
   wvv.loadUrl(QRurl);
  WebSettings webSettings = wvv.getSettings();
  webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  }}
```

This my code in scanner I just copied the zxing scanner from some tutorials

```
package com.project.ciisapp.ciis;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class ReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button database;
private Button scan_btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);
    database=(Button)findViewById(R.id.database);
    scan_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.scan_btn);


    database.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ReaderActivity.this,Main2Activity.class));
        }
    });



    final Activity activity=this;
    scan_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null){
        if(result.getContents()==null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You cancelled the scanning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {


            Intent intent = new Intent(this, scannner.class);
            intent.putExtra("QRurl", String.valueOf(result));
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    }
    else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How are you encoding the images? It's failing at the decode because there's extra data. Try checking out https://github.com/mlizbeth/Apotheosis/blob/master/src/main/java/io/valhala/tss/Inventory/view/InventoryView.java#L631 
It's plain Java but should be easily convertible to android.
and https://github.com/mlizbeth/Apotheosis/blob/master/src/main/java/io/valhala/tss/Inventory/view/InventoryView.java#L515 shows the function for viewing the QR image in real time.

Comment: I'm just trying pass the url only but someone said that it holds several pieces of information. this is my first time in zxing I'm still not used to it

Comment: Yes, you have to decode the image first. Try using the zxing online decoder and see if your QR decodes properly. If it does your logic is wrong somewhere

Comment: Raw text 
http://peter42398.000webhostapp.com/
Raw bytes 
42 46 87 47 47 03 a2 f2   f7 06 57 46 57 23 43 23
33 93 82 e3 03 03 07 76   56 26 86 f7 37 46 17 07
02 e6 36 f6 d2 f0 ec 11   ec 11 ec 11 
Barcode format QR_CODE
Parsed Result Type URI
Parsed Result 
http://peter42398.000webhostapp.com/
This what the online decoder result

Comment: what's the link to the QR image

Comment: @mirGantrophy http://qr-generator.qrcode.studio/tmp/f5a7732cc6329908b6d4e7539bb799ff.svg?1548807572673 I only use qr generator havent implemented qr generator in my web

Comment: @mirGantrophy do qr need decoder activity to convert it?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the screenshot, the address you're trying to visit is not a valid URL. It looks like an object holding several pieces of information about the scanned QR code is being transformed into a string representing the entire object, when you only want to pass the URL to the browser. Take a look at the object you get back from the scanner and grab only the QR code contents.

Comment: I put my code in scanner sir, Is this want you mean?